# Existence of GCD in an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the necessary and sufficient condition for an integral domain to have gcd for every pair of elements and why?

Comment: Well, it has to be a "gcd-domain", which is defined *precisely* as an integral domain in which every pair of elements has a gcd. Unique factorization is sufficient, but is not necessary (e.g., the ring of all algebraic integers). Every finitely generated ideal being principal (Bezout domain) is sufficient, but again not necessary (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}[x]$). In other words, you are asking for characterizations of GCD-domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a silly condition: every pair of elements in a domain $D$ has a gcd if and only if every pair of elements in $D$ has an lcm.

More seriously, a good survey is:

*GCD domains, Gauss' Lemma, and content of polynomials* by D.D. Anderson. In *Non-Noetherian commutative ring theory*, pages 1-13. Math. Appl. 520, Kluwer Acad, Publ., Dordrecht, 2000. MR 1858155 (2002g:13039).

Though, in general, the equivalent conditions are probably not what you are looking for (for example, one of the equivalent conditions is that a domain $D$ is a GCD-domain if and only if the group of divisibility of $D$ is a complete lattice ordered group).

Comment: Note that that silly condition is nontrivial! I'm going my memory here, but IIRC, if a pair of elements has an LCM, then it has a GCD, but the reverse doesn't hold.  You need that every pair of elements has a GCD in order to automatically get LCMs as well.  (Perhaps you can do it with less?  No idea.)

Comment: @Harry: By "silly" I did not mean "trivial"; but it's like the fact that every nonempty set that is bounded above has a supremum if and only if every nonempty set that is bounded below has an infinimum; in fact, it's essentially the same argument (the gcd of a and b is the lcm of all common divisors; the lcm of a and b is the gcd of all common  multiples). It's not really a good way to "characterize" GCD-domains, since it's a closely-related conditions that is usually about as hard to check.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin, I have small comment on the last paragraph of  your answer. I think $D$ is a GCD domain if and only if group of divisibility is a lattice ordered group. This is the theorem by Krull, Kaplansky and Jaffard.

Comment: This "silly condition" has since been proven at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148964/ .

Comment: @darijgrinberg: No, it’s not quite the same. The “silly condition” I give is that lcms for **every** pair exist is equivalent to gcds for **every** pair exist. That is not what is done in that question, where it is proven that the lcm for a **particular** pair $a$ and $b$ exists is equivalent to gcds for all pairs of the form $ra,rb$ exist. It’s not same assertion.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: As I note in the comment, you can prove that if all lcms exist, then gcds exist because the gcd of $a$ and $b$ is the lcm of all common divisors; and if all gcds exist, then the lcm is the gcd of all common multiples. You can see that it’s a different argument from that given in that link, which is a related but more restricted assertion.

Comment: Yeah, to be more precise it's a more general fact that is proven over there. I'm a bit unsure about your argument, though -- there are infinitely many common multiples, and we don't really want to assume that gcds of infinite sets exist, do we?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Okay, you may need to mod out by units, and bound above, say, "all common multiples that divide $ab$". Or extend to "all gcds exist" rather than just pairs.